# Stop form post php script from opening new page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form that is the same on several pages, so I have a php script that is invoked by all pages that have the contact form.  The script works fine, handles recaptcha, sends the email and all is good. But, everytime it runs, after the alert that tells the user the mail send was successful, it opens a blank page with the URL of the php script in it. I just want the page to stay where it was- display the success(or fail) alert, user clicks ok, and he is staring at the same page. Here's the form:

```
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h2>Contact Us</h2> Got a question ? Feedback? Awesome!
                        <form class="mt-4 mt-md-0" role="form" action="/php/mail.php" method="post" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="sr-only control-label">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control bg-faded-4" id="form_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="sr-only control-label">Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control bg-faded-4" id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message" class="sr-only control-label">Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control bg-faded-4" id="form_message" name="message" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                <span class="msg-error error"></span>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<MY_SITE_KEY>" style="padding-left: 15px"></div>                                    
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2" name="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is the php script:

```
<?php
  $errName = "";
  $errEmail = "";
  $errMessage = "";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = 'myform@mysite.com'; 
  $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
  $subject = 'Message from Contact Form ';

  $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}
else
  $sender_name = stripslashes($_POST["name"]);

// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))     {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
else
  $sender_email = stripslashes($_POST["email"]);

//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}
else
  $sender_message = stripslashes($_POST["message"]);

  $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => '<MY_SECRET_KEY>',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);


   // If there are no errors, send the email
    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
    } else if ( ($errName != "") ) {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please enter your name.');    </script>";
    } else if ($errEmail != "") {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You must enter a valid email address. Please try again.');</script>";
    } else if ( $errMessage != "") {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You must enter some message     text. Please try again.');</script>";
    } else {


      // All the neccessary headers for the email.
      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
          'From: ' . $from,
          'Reply-To: ' . $from,
          'Return-Path: ' . $from,
      );

      // Send email
      $mailResponse = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\n", $headers));
      if ( $mailResponse == 1 ) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('We\'ll be in touch!');    </script>";
      } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error sending message. Please try again.');</script>"; 
      }
    }
 ?>
```

I'm sure this is really ugly php code, haven't really done much php programming. But my real problem is this blank window that shows up after the form is processed by the php file- how can I stop it?

Thanks.....

So the last line of the php script now reads:

```
header('Location:http://sq36.cawgcap.org');
```

But here is what I see.
Before clicking 'Send':
[image]
And after the form is processed:
[image]

As soon as I click ok on the alert, I'm left staring at a blank page with address bar showing the location of the php script.

Comment: You could look into using Ajax. Then you can post the form without leaving the page in the first place. I also hope you have the contact form in it's own file which you include into all the pages you want it, and not have multiple copies of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the user using **location.href**. So after the alert code add: **`location.href="{url_of_your_form_page}";`**.

You should avoid the header function since it sends a http location header to the browser. It will cause the browser to redirect to the url without displaying the alert popup.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed to know. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

> Just redirect the user on some other page.

Use `header()` function.

When the script ends, just redirect the user on some other page, like `thanks.php` that may contain a thank you message or like `mail_sent_successfully.php`.

it is achieved by using [`header()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in php.

It is used like this

`header('Location: mail_sent.php');`

So add this line and the user will redirect to the `mail_sent.php` page.

Comment: You understood @cpeddie or you want further clarification?

Comment: tried this and it didn't work. See updated question.